# how get the lower dates Laravel and mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have this laravel query to get all  expired users from database

```
 $result = DB::table('radchecks as c')->leftJoin('radusergroup', 'c.username', '=', 'radusergroup.username')->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(c.expiration,'%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT('NOW()','%Y-%m-%d')")
->select('c.username', 'expiration')

->groupBy('c.username')
->get();
```

but this query return null even if  there are expiration column with value

```
 01 june 2017
```

but not return it . 
where is my wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put NOW() in single quotes `'NOW()'`

```
->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(c.expiration,'%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')")
```

Also your select list is invalid due expiration isn't present in group by or selected without aggregation this might result as indeterminate value, you could update select part as MAX(expiration)/MIN(expiration)

```
->select('c.username', DB::raw('MAX(expiration)'))
```